# What are the observable differences between "pure" antisocial personality disorder and psychopathy?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, personality-disorder

How to decide whether one has antisocial personality disorder, psychopathy, or both?

What are the traits which non-psychopaths with APD have but psychopaths don't have, or vice versa?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. We work differently to many SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/20135/7604

Comment: @Chris Rogers  - The only resemblance between the two questions is that they both are something about psychopathy. Similarly you could arbitrarily get any question which mentions psychopathy and claim that it is  "related" to mine.

Answer (score 1):

Antisocial personality disorder (APD) and psychopathy are not distinct entities, but highly overlapping constructs. APD is the diagnosis currently supported by the latest iterations of the [Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (DSM-5)](https://www.psychiatry.org/psychiatrists/practice/dsm), and psychopathy is rarely used in clinical contexts today, though the terms are often used interchangeably.

The [criteria of APD](https://www.psi.uba.ar/academica/carrerasdegrado/psicologia/sitios_catedras/practicas_profesionales/820_clinica_tr_personalidad_psicosis/material/dsm.pdf) are centered around antisocial behaviors such as norm violating behavior, impulsivity, aggressiveness, and a lack of remorse. Psychopathy lacks a specific set of criteria, but for instance the often used [Hare Psychopathy Checklist (PCL-R)](http://www.hare.org/scales/pclr.html)include aspects such as impulsivity, aggressivity, and a greater focus than APD on the lack of empathy and Machiavellianism, that is manipulativeness and callousness.